# How to get products by CategoryId in Prestashop?

Tags: php, plugins, prestashop

So what i am trying to do here is create a module which will return product data in specific category.

This is what i have so far:

```
$CategoryId="";
$category = new Category($CategoryId);
$all_products=(array)Category::getProducts($this->context->language->id, $page_number = $pageNumber, $nb_products = $nbProducts, $order_by = null, $order_way = null);
```

As a response I get 500 Internal Server Error. What am i doing wrong here? I know that something is off, but I am not that good with php to tell.

Comment: If u enable debug mode you will be able to see what causes the error. In config/defines.inc.php set define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true). From your code it seems like CategoryId is empty. Do u set its value in your shop?

Answer (score 0):

Point 1 You do not specify category.

```
$CategoryId="";
```

Point 2 You have copied Category::getProducts signature instead properly pass parameters.

You wrote:

```
$all_products=(array)Category::getProducts($this->context->language->id, $page_number = $pageNumber, $nb_products = $nbProducts, $order_by = null, $order_way = null);
```

and it is

```
$all_products=(array)Category::getProducts($this->context->language->id, $page_number, $nb_products, $order_by, $order_way);
```

If it does not fix the error, we need more info.